# How to convert subquery objects into ResultProxy class when joined in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an ORM class and a subquery. I created a join between the two and I want to access the subquery fields as an class may be a dummy ResultProxy object.

Code example:

```
session.query(ORM_Class,subqyery).\
       join(subqyery,ORM_Class.id==subqyery.id).all()
```

It would result me in a tupled resultset which has first object of ORM_CLass which makes sense but the rest id field would be just pure values of the subquery.

### Output

```
[(orm.my_orm.ORM_Class Object , 1)]
```

1 is the Id coming from the subquery part. I want to access id as ResultProxy.id or any other form similar.

Can we explicitly type cast into some other form?

Comment: Your output most probably is a list of [`KeyedTuple`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple) instances, so if select list items have labels, you can access them using such. You've failed to include the definition of the actual subquery, so you might be looking for something as simple as a call to `label()` in the right spot.

Comment: Label does help in referring to the field but does not convert into another object type. I mean I can access through subquery.c.label_name but when running the query with join statement those are treated as just values in the tuple.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. You seem to think that "converting subquery objects into ResultProxy" is an answer to your problem, so you ask about that instead of asking about the original problem. What do you really mean, when you say "I want to access the subquery fields as an class [sic]"? Would you like to [alias](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.aliased) the subquery to some mapped class? Or [bundle](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Bundle) it?

Comment: If I am able to get the values in class then I would be able to access the attributes with `getattr` method and would make my code cleaner. Currently, I am accessing those field by tuple index like row[2] which does not seems to be a nicer way. I am not sure about how bundle works. Do you think it would be helpful in this case?

Comment: @mad, if my asnwer below was the one you're looking for, you might consider renaming your question to "How can I access the columns of the results of my joined subquery by attribute name?"

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@ilja-everilä](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%C3%A4) in the comments, each record of your query is a [`KeyedTuple`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple), which is like a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) in Python, which means each field in it has a position in the tuple but also an attribute name.

You can get a list of strings containing the attribute names of one of these records with the `.keys()` method, or if you actually have a column called `keys` that would blot out the `.keys()` method, you can also use the [`._fields`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple._fields) attribute. E.g.:

```
>>> myquery.all()[0].keys()
['ORM_Class', 'something_id']
```

or

```
>>> myquery.all()[0]._fields
['ORM_Class', 'something_id']
```

The above tells me I could access the second field using the `something_id` attribute:

```
>>> myquery.all()[0].something_id
235
```

You can also get a dictionary mapping all entity names of a record to their values using the [`._asdict()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple._asdict) method:

```
>>> myquery.all()[0]._asdict()
{'ORM_Class': <orm.my_orm.ORM_Class object at 0xdeadbeefc0ff>,
 'something_id': 235}
```